# Retrofit2: How to receive JSON response in object with different field names?

Tags: android, json, web-services, retrofit2

I have below JSON response for my android application (sent from Web Service):

```
{
    "result_code": 0,
    "status": "",
    "count": 2,
    "start_date": "2016-07-17T00:00:00",
    "end_date": "2018-07-18T23:59:00",
    "pagination_start": 1,
    "pagination_end": 10
}
```

I want to know how can I receive this response stored in an object with below format? My concern is about difference in name of fields.

```
public class Response {
    int result_code;
    String status;
    int count;
    Date startDate,endDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using GSON Serialized library

Add this dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

You can add you POJO like this using Serialized Annotation

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

@SerializedName("result_code")
@Expose
private Integer resultCode;

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;

@SerializedName("start_date")
@Expose
private String startDate;

@SerializedName("end_date")
@Expose
private String endDate;

@SerializedName("pagination_start")
@Expose
private Integer paginationStart;

@SerializedName("pagination_end")
@Expose
private Integer paginationEnd;
}
```

It will Serialized you object on the basis of given name in annotation and than you can give whatever variable name for that field

Comment: Does `@Expose` is necessary?

Comment: Nope...that because i have generated code from jsonschema